# Strange SharePoint behaviour regarding "Check Permissions" in a web part

Tags: 2013, web-part, permissions, security, groups

I have a web part in which I am displaying users from User Profile Service which is synced with AD.

In my code I get all the users in current site and then see if they are part of any group. If they are then I get their First Name from UPS and display on screen.

I have a group named "Restricted Users" in which I have added all users as "Everyone" and "NT Authority\authenticated user".

On my web part page no users are displayed unless I do the following:

1. Go to site settings
2. Click on "Site permissions"
3. Click on "Check permissions", enter user name and press OK upon which it shows that this user is part of "Restricted Users" group.
4. Now after that when I refresh web part page, it shows that particular user.

Why is that? So basically I have to go and "Check permissions" for each user before they are displayed on page. This is very strange.

Comment: How do you check for the group membership? And if this is all you're doing why are you then recreating the MembersWebPart

Comment: I am not recreating members web part. I have a custom web part in which I display First Name name from UPS. And in my code I check whether user is part of any sharepoint security group. If yes then display name. But it doesn't display unless I specifically check for "Check permissions" for that user in Site Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from another forum and here it is.

> This is one of several pseudo groups.  There aren't any actual members
>   in this group.  It is used as a catch all in applications to represent
>   any user that has been authenticated.  Any user who is authenticated
>   by the system is automatically in this group.  Anyone who is not
>   authenticated by the system is automatically assigned the Guest user
>   account (which I believe is disabled by default in newer OS versions).
>   This user is not in the Authenticated Users group but they are in the
>   Guests group.  All users are in the Everyone group.